# Do I need to partition HDD?

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, ssd, dell-vostro

Do I need to partition my 1TB HDD for using with Ubuntu? It is installed as /dev/sda.

My OS files are located in 256GB SSD.

Also 15GB of HDD is already used but I can't see anything. Is this due to formatting?

Comment: I do not understand what "*15GB of HDD is already used but I can't see anything*" is supposed to communicate. Can you show us what you are looking at?

Comment: I was just looking at what are my content in HDD.

Comment: And you don't have any hidden files/folders? or maybe the bin? or maybe it's a factory reset partition, but it shouldn't appear in file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want Ubuntu installed on your drive: No, nowdays partitionning is not mandatory. Ubuntu can totaly be installed on one partition and in fact it's the default beahviour of Ubuntu installer.

Partitionning is only mandatory if you have mutiple OS.

Answer (score 1):

## You need to shrink your existing partition

Windows has created one huge partition covering all of your 1 TB HDD. They probably call it `D:\` or some such thing. You need to [shrink](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/resize-windows-10-system-partition/914938c2-a0f7-4ad0-9730-230ac6fe38ba) that NTFS formatted partition to make room for Ubuntu.

#### Do not create a new partition!

Make as much room for Ubuntu as you want it to have, 100 GB, 200 GB, 900 GB or whatever. However, **Do not create a new partition for Ubuntu, from within Windows!**. Ubuntu uses `ext4` partitions, and Windows do not know how to create them. Keep the space in the HDD **unallocated**.

Follow other instructions to prepare Windows for Ubuntu installation, such as disable fast-boot and hybernation etc.

When you start installing Ubuntu from the Live-USB, you will see an option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Select that. The Ubuntu installer will find the unallocated space in your 1 TB HDD and offer to install Ubuntu there.

Hope this helps